# Check in template if variable is an array, string, number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular5

I have a items array as shown below inside parent component.ts file

```
items = [
    {text: 'Length' , value: 10 },
    {text : 'Degree' , value : "108"},
    {text : 'Edges' , value : [10,20,30]}
]
```

Then I have a component named **app-label-values** placed inside a *ngFor Loop in parent component like show below

```
<div *ngFor ="let item of items">
  <app-label-values
   label="item.text"
   value = "item.value">
  </app-label-values>
</div>
```

**app-label-values** component purpose is to display label and value corresponding to the label.

For eg. Age : 10

The label here will always be a  text while the type of value can be dynamic ( number, strings, arrays)

So when the value is of type array I need to show only the length of the array ,like in our case the component should display 'Edges : 3' since [10,20,30].length is 3.

My aim is not to have this logic of type checking in the app-label-values component as I need it to be dumb and display only what is passed to it.

How can I solve this from parent component itself while rendering.

Kindly help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `value = "item.value.length"` ??

Comment: @GeorgeBailey That wont work as for number type values , value.length will throw and error and even though I convert number to string and apply length on it it will give me undesired result. eg. '10'.length = 2

Comment: Ok. I didn't really try this but you can check with `value = "item.value.constructor == Array ? item.value.length : item.value"`

Comment: Thanks George, constructor check appears to be a cleaner approach to me.Thanks :)

Comment: value = "item.value.push ? item.value.length : item.value".I did this and it works in the template as well, as push method only belongs to array prototype.However I hope i get a better solution than this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an `ngIf` to check if the `item.value` has a length property.
In the parent component,you can still pass to the child `item.value` and in the child component you display the value depending on the fact that it is an array or a number

1. **check length property**

```html
   <div *ngIf="item.value?.length > {{item.value.length}} </div>
```

If you want to pass directly the length of array to your child component, you can consider using a ternary operator

```
value="item.value?.length ? item.value.length : item.value"
```

If you want to check for string value, you first check if there is a length property. Then one can use the `+` operator to parse the string. And with a second ternary operator, you can check if that is a number or an array

```
value="item.value?.length ? +item.value ? item.value : item.value.length : item.value"
```

2. **check constructor name**

```html
value="item.value.constructor.name === "Array" ? item.value.length : item.value"
```

Using the constructor, one can check also if the value is a string, number,  etc.. [live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/check-type)

Comment: This might fail when it encounters string value as both array and string have length  property.

eg. [10,20,30].length = 3; '10'.length = 2

Comment: In your question, you said that it is number or array. If it is a string, you can parse it to a number before

Comment: edkeveked - As @George mentioned, checking via constructor seems to be more clean as we need not worry about parsing for  string and number.Only display the length when the constructor is Array else display as it is.Please correct me know if I am wrong.

Comment: value = "item.value.push ? item.value.length : item.value".I did this and it works in the template as well, as push method only belongs to array prototype.However I hope i get a better solution than this.

Comment: I edited the answer. I added how to check directly using the constructor

Comment: value="item.value.constructor.name === "Array" ? item.value.length : item.value" works.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use if Else statement in the template with angular 4 and on wards...

```
<div *ngFor ="let item of items">
    <app-label-values *ngIf="item.value.length >= 0; else elseIfTemp" label="item.text" value = "item.value.length"> </app-label-values>
    <app-label-values label="item.text" value = "item.value" #elseIfTemp> 
    </app-label-values>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method who will cehck the type and return accordingly

here's is example

```
<div *ngFor ="let item of items">
  <app-label-values
   label="item.text"
   value = "checkType(item.value)">
  </app-label-values>
</div>
```

and in .ts file

```
checkType(value){
  if(typeof value === 'object'){
    return value.length;
  }else{
    return value;
  }
}
```

[here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsxtfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) is an example

Comment: thanks Aniket.However Is'nt calling a method within the template a bad practise as the method gets called too many times.? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes but if you check the length inside html then it gives the string value length as well. that is why i am using method. and you are right, This method will get call multiple times as array length.

Comment: As @George mentioned, checking via constructor seems to be more clean as we need not worry about string and number.Only display the length when the constructor is Array else display as it is.

Comment: yes I tried and it did not work.So I found a fix as 
value = "item.value.push ? item.value.length : item.value".I did this and it works in the template as well, as push method only belongs to array prototype.However I hope i get a better solution than this.